# Bones don't appear in Action Editor at all

Tags: animation, armature

[image: Screenshot of my work]

[image: Tutorial with bones appearing in action editor]

Hi there, I'm new to Blender.

I've watched a few tutorials where all of the bones are selected. And then Alt+G and Alt+R are pressed, then the bones appear listed in green in the Action Editor. (To make a simple walking animation).

Pressing them resets the pose for me but does not show anything in the Action Editor.

How can I make the bones appear in the action editor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Dope Sheet* you've enabled the *Only Selected Objects* option, so you'll only see the tracks and keyframes of the bones that are selected (if keyframes have been created for these bones! as pointed out by Batfinger). In the video he also has this option enabled but he has selected all his bones.

[image]

Comment: May be worth mentioning will  also show nothing if no keyframes inserted. (after new blank action added via action editor)

Comment: I've edited, tell me if this is what you mean